# A very interesting problem on simple harmonic motion and detailed analysis of momentum and energy involved

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, oscillators

I am a high school student and I am a little confused in a question. this is a problem from Simple harmonic motion, I have found its solutions on many places but no solution turns out be convincing

[image: this image shows the problem]

This question says that: We are placing a 3kg block on a particle of mass 1Kg which is executing simple harmonic motion and passing through it mean position. Now we know when we place it on the 1Kg block kinetic friction will act between them and after a certain time they will come to a common velocity and now onwards static friction will act between them, some people conserve the linear momentum here ,in order to find their common maximum velocity and then they find the new amplitude either by conserving energy after the block has been placed or by taking the ration of their common maximum velocity, they say that there is no external force at the mean position {spring force=0) on the system{3kg mass+1kg mass) so we can conserve the momentum, but I don't think its true because spring force is 0 just for that moment, and I think that by the time they reach common velocity the spring force will no longer be 0, for linear momentum to be conserved the external force  must be 0 at each momentum, but here it is not 0 at each moment, so  I think it is not the right way to do it? but if we conserve the momentum then only we can get the right answer why?

The next thing I want to ask is that, suppose if this 3Kg block is placed on 1kg block not when it is passing through it mean position but when it is at its extreme position, and it is given that static friction between them is sufficient to avoid any slipping, so now as there is no kinetic friction acting I think now energy should be conserved before and after the 3Kg block has been placed, so I think that the amplitude will remain the same, is it true? and suppose if 3kg block is placed on it at a position in between mean position and extreme position,so how do we solve the problem then?? we cannot conserve momentum as well as energy now ,so how do we find he new amplitude

Comment: you're right to be suspicious about the how the spring force is 0 for only an instant, but I believe that is embedded in the question that during the collision there is no force on the system; hence the conservation of momentum applies. You're second question is more interesting I think because it addresses the conservation of momentum in non inertial frames; which still holds; although you have to account for the $\textbf{fictitious}$ force of the frame

Comment: sorry,,but I am a high school student as I mentioned,,,and I only know basics to solve the problem,,,can you please put forward a simplified answer so that  I can also understand easily:)....I think we cannot conserve the momentum at any point in this problem as there is always an external force acting,,,but we can conserve the energy In the 2nd question that I have asked?,,You are saying that my second question addresses the conservation of momentum in non inertial frames,,can u please explain how?? I think I have not said it anywhere?

Comment: Note that conservation of momentum can always be applied in separate dimensions. Here you can apply it in horizontal direction and get the answer without worrying about vertical direction in which it is 0 all time.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the differential equation $\ddot{x}+\omega^2x=0$ can be given as;
$$x=A\cos(\omega t)+B\sin(\omega t).$$
Before adding the other block, the position of the block performing SHM can be given as $$x(t)=x_0\cos(\omega t)+\frac{v_0}{\omega}\sin(\omega t)$$
Here $x_0$ denotes the equilibrium position and $v_0$ denotes the velocity of the block at $x_0$. Now we would like to add the new block and following the assumptions in the problem, we say;
$$\fbox{$x'(t)=x_0\cos(\omega't)+\frac{m_1v_0}{(m_1+m_2)\omega'}\sin(\omega't)$}$$
Note: $x'(t)$ denotes the position of the new mass (two blocks combined) and $\omega'\equiv \sqrt{\frac{k}{m_1+m_2}}$ where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the mass of the first and second blocks respectively. So the new amplitude $A'$ would be the maxima of the latter equation. I hope it helps!